# Не могу получить функцию из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть скрипт где создаются объекты и мне нужно к нему обратиться через Другой скрипт чтоб игрок когда его задевал, с ним происходили какие-то действия, но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к нему, вылетает следующая ошибка

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RandomSpawn.SpawnRandom () (at Assets/Scripts/RandomSpawn.cs:19)
PlayerController.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:83)
```

вот скрипты по [ссылке](https://jsfiddle.net/35a1dywL/)

Я погуглил и дело было в том, что я основном классе не инициализировал объект, я это сделал:

```
RandomSpawn Spawn = new RandomSpawn();
```

Но эта ошибка все равно вылетатет...
Есть предположения, что нужно инициализовать еще и объекты в этой функции, тоесть `Coin` и Массив `listObjects`
Но как это сделать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class RandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] listObjects;
public GameObject Coin;


int random;
void Start()
{
random = Random.Range(0, listObjects.Length);
SpawnRandom();
}
public void SpawnRandom()

{
Instantiate(Coin, listObjects[random].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

Сюды нужно вставить `SpawnRandom`

```
RandomSpawn Spawn = new RandomSpawn();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
{



if (collision.tag.Equals("Coin"))
{
HealthBar.fill += 0.2f;
Destroy(collision.gameObject);
Spawn.SpawnRandom();
}
}
```

Также я сделал вот так (это костыльно, ибо я хочу чтобы передавалась функция, а не полностью объект создавать, но это хотя бы как-то) и вроде бы я через Spawn обратился к этим объектам, но все равно не работает

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    private float moveInput;


    public float JumpForce;

    public bool isGrounded = false;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public float GroundRadius = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrounded;


   

    private bool playerLeft = false;

    private RandomSpawn Spawn;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        // Проверка, игрок на земле или нет
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, GroundRadius, whatIsGrounded);

        // Движение игрока
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        
        // Прыжок игрока
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            
            Jump();
        }

        // Поворот игрока  
        if (playerLeft == true && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
            
            
            
        }else if (playerLeft == false && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
            
        }

        // Смерть игрока
        if (HealthBar.fill <= 0)
        {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
           
        }
        
    }
    
   
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.tag.Equals("Coin"))
        {
            HealthBar.fill += 0.2f;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);   
            Instantiate(Spawn.Coin, Spawn.listObjects[Spawn.random].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }   
        if (collision.tag.Equals("Water"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        if (collision.tag.Equals("Enemy"))
        {
            HealthBar.fill -= 0.5f;
        }   
    }
    void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * JumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        playerLeft = !playerLeft;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```

Comment: не вдавался в подробности, но ошибка возникала из-за того что ты не закинул в инспекторе объект со скриптом RandomSpawn

Comment: Обратился к `listObjects[x]` которого не существует.